# what is "self.class.include?" means here?

Tags: ruby

```
if self.class.include?(Msf::Payload::Single) and
  self.class.include?(Msf::Payload::Stager)
  self.module_info['Stage'] = {}
```

I tried to execute "puts self.class" output was "Object". Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Object.method(:include?)` reveals that this method is [`Module#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-include-3F) – it checks whether the given module was included in the receiver.

Comment: @pushpamk it's always helpful to have some context. Add the project's name and (if possible) provide a link to the code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.class`, called inside an instance method, returns the reference to the object class. The [`Module#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Module.html#method-i-include-3F) method returns `true` if the module passed as argument is included in the current module.

In other words, the code you referenced is actually checking if the class of the instance you are manipulating is mixing `Single` or `Stager` classes.

Here's an example:

```
module One
end

class Two
  include One
end

class Three
end

t = Two.new
t.class.include?(One)
# => true

t = Three.new
t.class.include?(One)
# => false
```